# adding a compute shader after a pipeline

Tags: vulkan

I am writing a program to add a compute shader after rendering my image, and add a graphics pipeline after the compute shader to present the final image.
I have a question though. How should I set the camera to be that of my original 3D scene instead of that of the second graphics pipeline.

Comment: "*How should I set the camera to be that of my original 3D scene instead of that of the second graphics pipeline.*" I don't really understand. The data representing a "camera" is undoubtedly something you read through a descriptor resource. And since graphics pipelines are not descriptor layout compatible with compute pipelines, you will *have to* change descriptor sets. So... what's the problem?

Comment: i have another graphics pipeline after the compute shader to render the image output by the compute shader. This second graphics pipeline also has camera itself. I am thinking when I drag the image, how to turn the 3D model and not the camera of the second graphics pipeline

Comment: This sounds like a question about the engine or framework you're using rather than a question about Vulkan. Vulkan doesn't have anything to do with input handling or camera control, so what happens when you drag the image is up to your application to update the proper camera matrices that you send to your shaders.